# Using Protecting Strike to grant temporary hitpoints outside of an encounter?

Tags: dnd-4e, shaman

Outside of combat, does the following work...

1. Call your Spirit Companion and gather everyone around it
2. Use Protecting Strike on the spirit companion itself (since it is in range of "melee spririt 1" and able to be targeted with "Target: One creature").
3. Everyone now has [const-mod] temp hp until the next rest.
4. Possibly you suffer [5 + 1/2 level] damage if the spirit companion dies in the process.

... and if it works, does the shaman gain temporary hitpoints before or after taking damage from the spirit disappearing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You can't gain benefits from attack powers outside of real combat

Attack powers require you to be attacking a legitimate threat in order to gain benefits from their hit effects.

> #### LEGITIMATE TARGETS
>
> When a power has an effect that occurs upon hitting, missing, or otherwise affecting a target, the effect takes place only if the target in question is a meaningful threat. For instance, characters can gain no benefit from carrying a sack of rats in the hope of healing their allies by hitting the rats.

<sup>Rules Compendium, pg 108</sup>

As [Protecting Strike](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Protecting_strike) only applies temporary HP on a Hit, you're not able to gain this benefit unless you're using the power in an actually threatening situation, so having your spirit smack itself to get temp HP isn't a valid option.